# Reporting / flattening data from Cloudant - is dashDB the only option?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

I am considering to store a stream of IoT data into the CloudantDB (it looks like a native choice with IoT and Node-Red) I'd like to get some reporting / visualization on top of the data.

Apparently the Bluemix integrated choice is the dashDB warehouse where I could import the data and build reports I need. As a downsize - the dashDB seems to be priced monthly per instance (where for the monthly fee looks reasonable while in production). I just hesitate to pay for a whole month just to try it out.

So - is there other option to get the Cloudant data for for reporting / visualization? (ok, I can still build an ETL to push the data into an SQL dataabase) Is there something available out-of-box?

Note:
 For long term stats I could still define indexes or aggregate objects, but it's not that flexible

Comment: What are you using for the reporting? There are actually a ton of good visualisation engines which deal with JSON data. I use https://www.highcharts.com/ a lot.

Comment: @EdShee I see. Thank you for the tip. I expected something out of Bluemix, however this looks good. If I'd consider Cloudant as a JSON data source, there are a few tools to handle reporting over remote JSON data (as extra seems its better to prepare already aggregated values)

Comment: There is also a tool called data connect - https://www.ibm.com/uk-en/marketplace/data-connect - which you can use to export to a different SQL database if DashDB is not ideal

Comment: @EdShee thank you Ed, nice option, there are plenty of SQL reporting tools to be used out-of-box. We will take this option in account when we will get to it :)